# crystal reports how to align logo?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crystal-reports

I want to center align a logo in crystal report. but don't know how to do that. I tried use alignment options of visual studio but they align if any two objects are selected and they set alignment between them.

Kindly guide how I can align a logo in crystal report. I am using Crystal reports with C# and Winform in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

In design view, you can see a ruler on top of the report. Count the ruler's length, divide it by 2 and match that point with your logo's mid point.

OR

Click on ruler and create a seekbar arrow. Match the mid point of the logo by moving your image to the arrow. Now drag the arrow to the mid point of the ruler, you can see your logo moves along the arrow. See the below image.
[image: Image or logo align]